# Varchar converted datetime checking between varchar date ranges. Is it the right way to check?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was going through some queries and found some where clauses the following way

`convert(varchar, datefield, 101) between convert(varchar, @startdate, 101) and convert(varchar, @enddate, 101)`

My question is this the right approach to check a `datetime` value between date ranges? Will this approach fetch me the **wrong** value? If so, please provide some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert your Date to a `varchar` and compare because `string` **comparisson** is not fast. It is much faster if you use `>=` and `<` to filter your `date` column.

DO NOT use the following, as it could return some records from `@enddate` if their times are 00:00:00.000.

```
datefield between @startdate and @enddate
```

Fastest way to convert `datetime` to `date`.

On SQL Server 2008 and higher, you should convert to `date`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

1. No varchar<->datetime conversions required
2. No need to think about locale